# Is there a way to expect a timeout?

Tags: java, junit5

Currently, I'm writing some integration tests and I need to assert that a call to a method blocked the calling thread for at least x seconds. The thing is I have method that will block forever and I need to assert that it has been blocked for at least x seconds. Is there any way to do that? The only other answer is about JUnit4 and we are using JUnit 5... In advance thank you for your answer.

Comment: what about thread.sleep?

Comment: @Pirate I've clarified my question ^^

Comment: I haven't got your real problem. Do you need check the time from specific mocked method? Or you need fake some delay on specific method?

Comment: @DilermandoLima I just need something like assertThrows that ensures that the runnable I gave it ran for at least x seconds and is still running at this time. idk if it was clearer

Comment: So if you need ensure the time and runnable you can mock this method and implement `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(xxx)`, this way your method will do what you need  to ensuring

Comment: You can use "https://www.baeldung.com/awaitlity-testing" awaitlity

Comment: If you want to test if something is executing in a method, you may use "wait(long timeout)/notify" pattern in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `assertTimeout(Duration timeout, Executable executable)` for your problem. For more info, you should visit [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions).

```java
    @Test
    void timeoutNotExceeded() {
        // The following assertion succeeds.
        assertTimeout(ofMinutes(2), () -> {
            // Perform task that takes less than 2 minutes.
        });
    }

    @Test
    void timeoutNotExceededWithResult() {
        // The following assertion succeeds, and returns the supplied object.
        String actualResult = assertTimeout(ofMinutes(2), () -> {
            return "a result";
        });
        assertEquals("a result", actualResult);
    }

    @Test
    void timeoutNotExceededWithMethod() {
        // The following assertion invokes a method reference and returns an object.
        String actualGreeting = assertTimeout(ofMinutes(2), AssertionsDemo::greeting);
        assertEquals("Hello, World!", actualGreeting);
    }

    @Test
    void timeoutExceeded() {
        // The following assertion fails with an error message similar to:
        // execution exceeded timeout of 10 ms by 91 ms
        assertTimeout(ofMillis(10), () -> {
            // Simulate task that takes more than 10 ms.
            Thread.sleep(100);
        });
    }

    @Test
    void timeoutExceededWithPreemptiveTermination() {
        // The following assertion fails with an error message similar to:
        // execution timed out after 10 ms
        assertTimeoutPreemptively(ofMillis(10), () -> {
            // Simulate task that takes more than 10 ms.
            new CountDownLatch(1).await();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I opted for a different strategy. You see my use case is to test if some JDBC Postgres transactions would block. Instead, I'll just wait that the transaction timeout to kick in and assert the time between the beginning of my test and when the timeout triggered. Thank you all for taking some valuable time to answer my question.